# Pigeonhole Principle / Number Theory

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, pigeonhole-principle

Let $S$ be a subset of $A=\{1,2,3,...,1000\}$. Find the largest number of elements in $S$ such that for any $a, b \in S$ with $a>b$, $a-b$ does not divide $a+b$.

I've tried numerous approaches, even brute force (listing), but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Sorry, but "Find the largest number of elements in $S$ such that" seems unclear to me. What do you mean with the largest number of elements? Do you mean the $S$ with the greatest possible cardinality?

Comment: Among all sets $S$ with the stated property, find the cardinality of the set with the greatest cardinality.

Comment: What is the source of the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint. $S$ cannot contain consecutive numbers, because if $a-b=1$ then $a-b$ divides anything. $S$ cannot contain numbers 2 units apart, because if $a-b=2$ then $a$ and $b$ have the same parity, so $a+b$ is even, hence $a-b$ divides $a+b$.

Now, can $S$ contain numbers 3 units apart?

Comment: This is a good way to attaack the problem.